# Decompiling obfuscated Android dex/jar files into Java source code

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler, deobfuscation

Are there ways to decompile obfuscated dex/jar files into Java source code? I have an APK with no classes.dex file within it, but I have the odex file. I've tried using oat2dex and dex2jar to get the dex/jar files, and then used a few decompilers to get the Java source, but I'm either getting errors on some parts, or really hard to read code since it's obfuscated.

Here's what I've tried

- JD-GUI (first I've tried that completed decompilation, but with multiple errors)
- Fernflower (couldn't complete)
- Procyon (pretty good, but with some errors)
- CFR (better, but with some errors)
- Jadx (best, with least errors, but code is still obfuscated and hard to read, with multiple classes/methods with the same random names)

What can I do to get more readable code?

Comment: Why are you decompiling obfuscated code? Making this difficult is the purpose of obfuscation tools.

Comment: If there is a good one, i think people will stop obfuscating their code.

Comment: So am I right to say there's no solution?

Comment: The Krakatau decompiler is specifically designed for handling obfuscated code. However, there's nothing that will magically fix gibberish names.

Comment: To "Fix" gibberish names you'll have to manually remap classes with a deobfuscator program like Enigma. Or if you can use a decompiler to get the source, you can do that all in your IDE (but it does take longer to do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any magical tool that will refactor all your obfuscated code into something meaningful and "clean". Obfuscated code is obfuscated: deal with it.

You can however save the obfuscated source code, create a project with your prefered ide (that support refactor) and manually analize functions and variables and refactor them to something meaninful. This require a lot of time, but eventually you will obtain an almost clean source code.